# SQL partition achieving "second_value" etc

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, window-functions, over-clause

I'm calculating customers retention and want to segment my customers according to behavior in first, second, third and so-on purchases.

For example:

```
using first_value(had_coupon) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date DESC)
```

I can segment by using a coupon in the first purchase effect retention.

I'm trying to figure out to do the same thing for the second and third purchase.
Using the CASE statement I can give another value to customers who did not buy two, three or more times.

I've been using [this site](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) for help.

Comment: For any data questions you should include sample input data and the expected result.

Comment: Could you explain further what you want to achieve? A small dataset, expected result plus what you tried so far would really help

Comment: hey. I want to segment my customers based on coupon usage behavior in their purchase-life.

Comment: SORRY, im new here:  hey. I want to segment my customers based on coupon usage behavior in their purchase-life. So far I used first_value for the first purchase, lead, and lag functions for trailing. However, my desired segmentation outcome is in the example column G and H: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sf1lCkVOnFKQiKfHHDvvof2VDR8DECcK3Q-_MpsjScM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` for marking first, second, third, etc + group by aggregation using `max()` or `min()` to group rows by customer/etc:

```
select max(case when rn=1 then had_coupon end) first_order_had_coupon,
       max(case when rn=2 then had_coupon end) second_order_had_coupon, 
       -- and so on
       --other group columns
from  
(
select had_coupon,
       --other columns
      row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by order_date DESC) rn
  from table
)s
group by group columns
```

Comment: Hey, your case statement gives True to all customers who bought in the first, second and so on time. In addition, it should be a window function because I want to segment a user by this their coupon behavior:  a second purchase coupon user has to have in their fourth purchase row a True for the column: "coupon in the second purchase".

Comment: @oshrim It's difficult to understand, please provide data example with desired output

Comment: does this sample dataset help to understand my desired outcome? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sf1lCkVOnFKQiKfHHDvvof2VDR8DECcK3Q-_MpsjScM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @oshrim Please add it to the question, maybe someone will help. I still do not understand what is wrong with second purchase. For customer 1st is 01/11/2018, second is 18/02/2018 (second date< first). Fir customer2 second date> first. The order is different?